# Lazy load tabs with complex label

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

In Angular Material, I want to have lazy-loaded tabs with labels which are contained title and icon.
In [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) told use `matTabContent` and put body inside `ng-template` for lazy loading. Also, for complex labels use `mat-tab-label` directive and put the label inside `ng-template`.
When I use both together, it doesn't work correctly.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
<mat-tab>
  <ng-template matTabContent mat-tab-label>
  <mat-icon>people</mat-icon>
 <span class="title">info</span>
    <app-group-info></app-group-info>
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab>
  <ng-template matTabContent mat-tab-label>
  <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
 <span class="title">purchases</span>
    <app-group-purchase-list></app-group-purchase-list>
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some ideas and finally found the solution:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
 <mat-tab>
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
   <mat-icon>people</mat-icon>
   <span class="title">info</span>
  <ng-template>
  <ng-template matTabContent>
   <app-group-info></app-group-info>
  </ng-template>
 </mat-tab>
 ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: the `title` class came from?